# 100vw image inside of 1024px container causing small horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css

100vw image inside of 1024px container causing small horizontal scroll.

**Expected:** Image is full with of page without causing a horizontal  scrollbar.

It seems to work perfectly well, but I am getting a very slight horizontal scroll.

*The other related answer I have found do not seem to address this.*

```
.container {
    max-width: 1024px;
    width: 98%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.full-image{
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50vw;
}
```

Shortened HTML

```
<div class="container">
 <figure>
   <img src="..." class="full-image">
 </figure>
</div>
```

*Does 100vw not account for the vertical scrollbar possibly?* I am going to guess it is one of many other things going on, but hoping someone has dealt with this and knows off the top what may be causing it.

Comment: you want your image to extend outside the container and cover all the screen?

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes!

Comment: why not just put that figure tag outside the container? Using 98% and auto margins could add a small space on both sides and 100vw is full width of the window. no wonder you're getting overflow. Putting it outside the container would prevent that.

Comment: @KaiQing that would work but the content is generated dynamically, think blog post, I don't want to get too verbose. I need it simple, image with class = full width.

Comment: Why not give the image a `width:100%; height:auto;` so it takes 100% of the container? You would avoid cropping that way. height auto is to force aspect ratio preservation. You may need !important on that.

Comment: @KaiQing we are going for 100% of viewport here. The Image expands outside of the container.

Comment: Right but the accepted answer won't do that. It might look like it is in some breakpoints but as soon as your body is over 1024 it will center the container, which will put your image left alignment flush with the container and not the viewport, then crop at the edge of the container so your right side of the image would be cut off. If that's acceptable then sure, that would work.

Comment: Also, depending on how the dynamic content is handled, you could break out of the container in the markup and just re-open the tag after the image. I wouldn't be able to illustrate without knowing what is generating your markup. (wordpress, for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer would be to implement `overflow-x: hidden;` on your body tag itself. If you have no use case where the site should scroll horizontal then there shouldn't be any issue.

Answer (score -1):

`overflow: hidden;` hide the horizontal scroll

```css
.container {
    max-width: 1024px;
    width: 98%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.full-image{
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <figure>
   <img src="https://chainimage.com/images/1024-x-1024-464-kb-color-jpeg.jpg" class="full-image">
 </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: The purpose is to have the image overflowing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this confines the image to container. I updated my question to make this more clear.